# How to check if multiple rows of cells are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check all other cells in a table row to have a cell (there's a cell for each row, not one single cell) display either "entry missing" or "complete" automatically. Currently, I'm only able to make it work properly for the first row since I can only have it check the cells in the first row.

I've tried having the code iterate through the table, checking values of cells in the row with if statements and then either with the (this) function or using a ('#tdID') format.

I haven't been able to check any cell values in rows below the first when I don't use (this), but as far as I can tell, (this) only refers to the #DataEntryStatus id since it starts the function in the first line. Basically, I need something that works like (this) but with #Tool, #CutRef, and more td IDs.

```
$('#table_id #DataEntryStatus').each(function(){

    if($('#Tool').text() =="")$(this).text("Entry missing");
    else if($('#CutRef').text() =="")$(this).text("Entry missing");
    else($(this).text("Complete"));


    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() =="entry missing")$(this).css('background-color','#fcc');
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() =="complete")$(this).css('background-color','#af0');
});
```

And here is the table where the ids come from

```
<table class="table" id="table_id">
        <tr>
            <th style="color:#ddd">fffffffffffffff<br>f<br>f<br>f</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Data Entry Status</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Tool</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Cut Ref</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Date</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Coupon</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Row</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Axial</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Ox Pocket</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">SM Pocket</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Tray #</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Angle</th>
            <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Probe</th>

        </tr>


    <tbody id="myTable">
    {% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">! X !</a>
        </td>
        <td id="DataEntryStatus"><div>{{ item.DataEntryStatus }}</div></td>
        <td id="Tool"><div>{{ item.Tool }}</div></td>
        <td id="CutRef"><div>{{ item.CutRef }}</div></td>
        <td id="CutDate"><div>{{ item.CutDate }}</div></td>
        <td id="Coupon"><div>{{ item.Coupon }}</div></td>
        <td id="Row"><div>{{ item.Row }}</div></td>
        <td id="Axial"><div>{{ item.Axial }}</div></td>
        <td id="OxPocket"><div>{{ item.OxPocket }}</div></td>
        <td id="SmPocket"><div>{{ item.SmPocket }}</div></td>
        <td id="TrayNum"><div>{{ item.TrayNum }}</div></td>
        <td id="Angle"><div>{{ item.Angle }}</div></td>
        <td id="Probe"><div>{{ item.Probe }}</div></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want it to check each row individually and identify which rows are filled with values and which aren't, but currently it only checks the cells of the first row and prints the same output for every status cell in later rows.

Comment: Without more code to look at, I cannot say for certain what is happening. My initial thought is that since you are looking for an `ID` in your selector, jquery is returning zero or one object. https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ Try using a `.class` selector.

Comment: Duplicated `id`s might have to do with it, but what if you targeted `tr`s and `td`s directly? Can you show the row structure to see what are we working with?

Comment: @msg Edited the post to include the table to display the row structure now as well. If it matters, currently the DataEntryStatus object goes into the database, but I'm planning on changing that to just be an automatic and cosmetic cell on the table once I'm able to have it working correctly.

Comment: it works for the first row only since you are duplicating the id for each row. Use class instead of id to target multiple element in the dom. Id must be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate each `tr` in the table directly and then every cell. Reference for the [`:gt` pseudo selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```js
// Check each row in table
$('#table_id tbody tr').each(function() {
  $row = $(this)
  $status = $row.find('#DataEntryStatus');
  // Iterate every cell, but skip the first two in each row
  // (action and status cell). Be sure to update this value if you change
  // the table structure
  $row.find('td:gt(1) div').each(function() {
    $status.text("Complete").css('background-color', '#af0');
    if ($(this).text() == "") {
      $status.text("Entry missing").css('background-color', '#fcc');
      // The row is invalid, break from the each()
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th style="color:#ddd">fffffffffffffff<br>f<br>f<br>f</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Data Entry Status</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Tool</th>
    <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Cut Ref</th>
    <!-- Simplified for convenience -->
  </tr>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="{% url 'edit_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'delete_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">! X !</a>
      </td>
      <td id="DataEntryStatus">
        <div>DataEntryStatus</div>
      </td>
      <td id="Tool">
        <div></div>
      </td>
      <td id="CutRef">
        <div>CutRef 1</div>
      </td>
      <!-- Simplified for convenience -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="{% url 'edit_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'delete_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">! X !</a>
      </td>
      <td id="DataEntryStatus">
        <div>DataEntryStatus 2</div>
      </td>
      <td id="Tool">
        <div>Tool 2</div>
      </td>
      <td id="CutRef">
        <div>CutRef 2</div>
      </td>
      <!-- Simplified for convenience -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, Here I am getting `each row`, Then getting `each cell/column` of that row, Then checking for empty....

You can replace with any value in `if` instead of `empty`...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='myTable' border>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row1 Col1
    </td>
    <td>
      Row1 Col2
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Row2 Col1
    </td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      Row3 Col2
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 
 <script>
 $("#myTable tr").each(function(rowNum,row){
  for(var i = 0; i < row.children.length; i++) {
  
      if(row.children[i].innerHTML == ""){
        row.children[i].innerHTML = "Entry Missing"; //Set text of current cell as 'Entry Missing'
      }
      
  }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Makes sense, but being quite new to javascript I'm not sure what to do with the console.log part. Seeing as I want the status displayed in cells on the table, I wouldn't use the console for that right? What would I replace that line with in that case though?